# Vim search and replace: change position of characters

Tags: vim, replace

I have strings like `(i,1)` and `(i,2)` in my text.

I want so search and replace them so i get
`(1,i)` and `(2,i)` respectively. How do I go about that in Vim?

Comment: is it always `(i, 1 or 2)`?

Comment: Plug for my [vim-argumentative](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative) plugin. Argumentative allows you to shift arguments via `>,` and `<,` which might be of some use to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:%s/(\([^,]\+\),\([^)]\+\))/(\2,\1)/g
```

Explanation:

- `:` gets you into command mode
- `%` apply the following command to each line
- `s` the command is *substitute*. It consists of two parts, the *pattern* and the *replacement*. These are 
       seperated by `/`
- `/` Seperator for *pattern*. The pattern is `(\([^,]\+\),\([^)]\))`

  - `(` You want to match an opening paranthesis
  - `\(` store the following matching part in `\1`.
  - `[^,]` match anything *except* `,`
  - `\+` match *at least* one (of the not `,`)
  - `\)` end the matching part for `\1`
  - `,` match the comma (don't store anywhere)
  - `\(` same as above, but store in `\2`
  - `[^)]` match anything *except* `)`
  - `\+` match *at least* one (of the not `)`)
  - `\)` as above
  - `)` match the closing paranthesis (don't store anywhere)
- `/` Seperator for *replacement*. The replacement is `(\2,\1)`

  - `(` literal insertion of `(`
  - `\2` insert 2nd match of *pattern*
  - `,` insert literal `,`
  - `\1` insert 1st match of *pattern*
  - `)` insert literal `)`
- `/` Seperator to indicate the end of *replacement*.
- `g`  so that the pattern is replaced multiple time on one line (necessary only if a line contains *(bbb,ccc)* multiple times)

Comment: I think an explanation would enhance the answer

Comment: a `*` or `+` in your group2 was missing, otherwise your line won't work for `(bar,foo)`. also `/g` flag is needed if the pattern shows more than once in a line.

Answer (score 2):

this command does it:

```
%s/(\zs\([^,]*\),\([^)]*\)\ze)/\2,\1/g
```

or

```
%s/\v\(([^,]*),([^)]*)\)/(\2,\1)/g
```

brief explanation:

```
\v      : very magic, to save some escapes
\(      : match openning "("
([^,]*) : group 1 the text between "(" and ","
,       : the comma
([^)]*) : group2 , the text between the "," and ")"
\)      : ending ")"
```

replacement part: `(\2,\1)` (swap the two groups)

Comment: I think an explanation would enhance the answer

Comment: Yes, an explanation/ a breakdown would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Marius added explanation

Comment: That's more useful. What's the \zs and \ze, btw ?

Comment: That was perhaps a more 'rhetorical' question :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a no-brainer, choose a macro (`:help q`) instead of search and replace (`:help :s`). I often go for macros if the search and replace patterns get complicated (e. g., they take more than one or two minutes to write). Macros are easy and intuitive, you perform your change once and simply repeat it. Solution for your problem using macros:

```
qq/(i,[12])<CR><SPACE>xpxp<BACKSPACE><BACKSPACE>xpq1000@q
```

That's 29 very easy keystrokes.

```
qq              Record following keystrokes in register q
/(i,[12])<CR>   Search for (i,1) or (i,2)
<SPACE>xpxp...  Your text manipulation
q               Stop recording
1000@q          Replay contents from register q 1000x
```

Don't worry, if one of the commands fail (in this case the search for `(i,1)`) repetition stops immediately. Of course you can also do it the safe way:

```
@q              Replay the keystrokes from register q (once)
@@              Repeat the last replay (that's easier than @q)
```

So you'd type something like `@q@@@@@@@@` to make the changes and check them.

Comment: I do agree sometimes it is best to use a macro. I personally don't see anything tricky with a couple of capture groups and a negated character classes. Your switch arguments can be generalized to `ldwpld])%p` for multiple character arguments. It is also probably worth mentioning `set nowrapscan` if we need to stop from wrapping around the buffer.

Comment: You're basically right, that pattern is easy and just requires only two capture groups. But already here you have to remember which of the two parentheses need to be escaped (this may also depend on your settings) -> needs brain power... Also a good point to mention with `nowrapscan` (should go with `gg`). But in most cases it doesn't matter if the search gets wrapped since you won't find the search pattern any more.